# Overwritten field when persisting with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When testing the persistence of my model I'm getting one attribute overwritten. I'm running the following test:

```
@Test
public void objectTest() throws Exception {
   tester.testClass(AssetUpdateReserve.class);       
   Assert.assertEquals(tester.getResult().getErrors().size(), 0, "Errors found");   
}
```

My AssetUpdateReserve Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET_UPD_RESERVE")
public class AssetUpdateReserve implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6530799190088978893L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "partitionId.assetSliceId", column = @Column(name = "PARTITION_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "partitionId.associatedKey", column = @Column(name = "PARTITION_ID_AK")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "containerId.id", column = @Column(name = "CONTAINER_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "containerId.associatedKey", column = @Column(name = "CONTAINER_ID_AK")) })
    private AssetUpdateReserveIndex id;

    // Default JSON/JAXB constructor
    public AssetUpdateReserve() {
    }
}
```

According to this I should have a primary key with four attributes. However, the same name in the associatedKey makes one of the attributes to be overwritten (in this particular case, CONTAINER_ID_AK overwrites PARTITION_AD_AK) That makes my primary key have only three fields. 
I've tried to comment the last @AttributeOverride, this fixes the problem and the table has the PARTITION_ID_AK column. However, I can't just dismiss the CONTAINER_ID_AK.

My other entities:

AssetSliceId

```
@Embeddable
public class AssetSliceId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9065665917069565503L;

    public static final int MAX_VALUE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    @Column(name = "ASSET_SLICE_ID")
    private Integer assetSliceId;

    @Column(name = "ID_AK")
    private String associatedKey;

    public AssetSliceId() {
        super();
    }
}
```

AssetUpdateReserveIndex:

```
@Embeddable
public class AssetUpdateReserveIndex implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1349614023445826884L;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "assetSliceId", column = @Column(name = "SLICE_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "associatedKey", column = @Column(name = "SLICE_ID_AK")) })    
    private AssetSliceId partitionId;

    @Embedded
    private InstanceId containerId;

    // Default JSON/JAXB constructor
    public AssetUpdateReserveIndex(){
        super();
    }
}
```

InstanceId

```
@Embeddable
public class InstanceId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6620668219143108192L;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "ID_AK")
    private String associatedKey;

    // Apenas para utilizacao TopLink / POF
    public InstanceId() {
    }
}
```

My persistence.xlm file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetSliceId</class>      <class>package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserve</class>       <class>package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserveIndex</class>       <class>package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.InstanceId</class      <class>package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.SubscriptionID</class>

            <properties>
            <!-- Default Login using Oracle for EclipseLink's internal connection pool -->

            <!--  HSQL -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/persistencetesterdb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally the log:

```
Call: DROP TABLE ASSET_UPD_RESERVE
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE ASSET_UPD_RESERVE")
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1549646215)--CREATE TABLE ASSET_UPD_RESERVE (CONTAINER_ID_AK VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONTAINER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PARTITION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PARTITION_ID_AK VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (CONTAINER_ID_AK, CONTAINER_ID, PARTITION_ID))
2014-07-03 18:20:06 INFO  - =============================================================================
2014-07-03 18:20:06 INFO  - Testing: class package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserve
2014-07-03 18:20:06 DEBUG - Persisting...
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(1549646215)--INSERT INTO ASSET_UPD_RESERVE (CONTAINER_ID_AK, CONTAINER_ID, PARTITION_ID, PARTITION_ID_AK) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [str3, str2, 1, str1]
2014-07-03 18:20:06 DEBUG - Retrieving...
2014-07-03 18:20:06 FATAL - [ERROR] Unexpected problem while persisting/retrieving following object:
{"package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserve": {"id": {"partitionId": {"assetSliceId": 1,"associatedKey": "str1"},"containerId": {"id": "str2","associatedKey": "str3"}}}}
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-202] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: An internal error occurred accessing the primary key object [package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserveIndex@6dc27e82].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserve --> [DatabaseTable(ASSET_UPD_RESERVE)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getIdentifier(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:717)
    at package.persistencetester.tester.jpa.bd.Datasource.getObjectId(Datasource.java:132)
    at package.persistencetester.tester.jpa.bd.Datasource.retrieveByObject(Datasource.java:127)
    at package.persistencetester.tester.jpa.JpaTester.testObjectPersistence(JpaTester.java:175)
    at package.persistencetester.tester.jpa.JpaTester.testClass(JpaTester.java:142)
    at package.persistencetester.tester.jpa.JpaTesterTest.objectTest(JpaTesterTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-202] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: An internal error occurred accessing the primary key object [package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserveIndex@6dc27e82].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(package.persistencetester.model.jpa.attroverride.AssetUpdateReserve --> [DatabaseTable(ASSET_UPD_RESERVE)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.errorUsingPrimaryKey(DescriptorException.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CMP3Policy$FieldAccessor.setValue(CMP3Policy.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.CMPPolicy.createPrimaryKeyInstance(CMPPolicy.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getIdentifier(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getIdentifier(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:715)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.findDeclaredField(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.findDeclaredField(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getField(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CMP3Policy$FieldAccessor.setValue(CMP3Policy.java:693)
    ... 32 more
[EL Config]: connection: Connection(1549646215)--disconnect
[EL Info]: connection: file:/C:/Users/x01709/workspace2/persistence-tester/src/core/target/test-classes/_jpa-test logout successful
[EL Config]: connection: Connection(1495651843)--disconnect
```

Note: In log you can see the create table and the primarykey only has 3 attributes but when the insert is made, has all four

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JPA API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html), "Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported."

Because both `containerId` and `partitionId` contain a field called `associatedKey`, and they can't be mapped to separate entities in the `@EmbeddedId` class, so the table wasn't created with all four values in the primary key (because it sees `associatedKey` twice, and discards the duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

have not much experience with object-relational mapping, but if your problem is to have two data with the same name, I think you can use `@ AssociationOverride`'ll show a link, http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/tutoriales.php?pagina=embedded_associationOverride it's what you want, the part of the page where makes the following is what I think can help you:

```
    @Embedded  
@AttributeOverrides(  {  
    @AttributeOverride(name="pesoMaximoEnKg", column = @Column(name="pesoMaximoEnKgConductor")),  
}  
@AssociationOverrides({  
    @AssociationOverride(name="cinturon",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cinturonConductor_id")),  
})  
Asiento asientoConductor;


@Embedded  
@AttributeOverrides(  {  
    @AttributeOverride(name="pesoMaximoEnKg", column = @Column(name="pesoMaximoEnKgCopiloto")),  
}  
@AssociationOverrides({  
    @AssociationOverride(name="cinturon",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cinturonCopiloto_id")),  
})  
Asiento asientoCopiloto;
```

P.S:the page is in Spanish but I think Google translator will do a good job.
if not what you want or does not serve you, I notify me that I delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at "flattened" `AssetUpdateReserveIndex` structure, you have two mappings for same attribute name (`associatedKey`), and latter overrides the former. I would expect some kind of validation exception from EclipseLink but what you see in the logs (3 attributes for create table, 4 for insert) may indicate that they didn't fully cover this particular case. Simple solution is to change the name of one of conflicting fields.